# Laravel 5 - image validation doesn't work

Tags: validation, laravel

I am using Laravel 5 Validator for validating avatars, my rules look like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(
    Request::all(),
    [
        'avatar' => 'required|image|max:1000'
    ]
);
```

I am trying to upload files and it always says "no file choosen". If I remove the required rule, then it works, even the max:1000 rule work.

Comment: Can you do a dd(Request::get('avatar')) before calling the make method? Are you trying to validate a form?

Comment: Can supply the code for your form please

Comment: Does your form has  `multipart/form-data` so it can work properly with files?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Yes, i did, you need to first type image and then all the other stuff.

Answer (score 29):

make sure that form accept files,

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true))
```

or

```
<form action="foo/bar" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Oh boy, thanks so much. Forgot to put the enctype and have been here looking at code for past hour. +1