# Laravel 8 file upload validation fails with any rule

Tags: php, laravel, file, validation, upload

I want to validate a file upload but with literally any validation rule, I get "The (name of input) failed to upload." I've seen this issue in a few places but none of the solutions worked for me.

I'm using Laravel 8.0, php 8.0.2, and nginx/1.18.0 on ubuntu.

Controller:

```
public function uploadMedia (Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'required',
        'alt' => 'required',
    ]);
    dd('valid');
}
```

Blade file:

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <p class="alert error">{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endif

<form method="POST" action="/media" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="text" name="alt" placeholder="Write a short description of the image under 160 characters." />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

If I get rid of the validation rule for 'file' it works, I get to the dd.

```
$request->validate([
    'file' => '', // works if I do this
    'alt' => 'required',
]);
```

I've seen other people have this issue and I've tried:

- Putting another rule (max:10000, image) instead of 'required'
  for the file – still get the same error.
- Changing the values php.ini to `post_max_size = 201M` and
  `upload_max_filesize = 200M` (this shouldn't be an issue in the
  first place because the image I am trying to upload is a 136kb jpg). Verified with `phpinfo();`
- After changing these values, reloading nginx and php-fpm
- Rebooting the VM
- Checking that all the double and single quotes are the correct character
- Trying to upload other filetypes like png or txt, same error.
- Putting 'image' as the first validation rule which worked for someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831599/laravel-5-image-validation-doesnt-work)
- Removing the extra comma at the end of the rules array
- Changing the name of the file input to something other than 'file'
- Using a different browser (Firefox and Chrome)
- Disabling all my browser extensions
- Writing the validation like this instead (still get the same error):

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'file' => 'required',
    'alt' => 'required'
]); 
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('/media')->withErrors($validator);
}
```

If I dd($request) before validating:

```
Illuminate\Http\Request {#44 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#255 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure() {#264 ▶}
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#46 ▶}
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#45 ▼
    #parameters: array:2 [▼
      "_token" => "RrjAA2YvnSd3EYqg8vAwoWT4y6VenJzGjb5S72SU"
      "alt" => "dsfghdf"
    ]
  }
  +query: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#52 ▶}
  +server: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ServerBag {#49 ▶}
  +files: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag {#48 ▼
    #parameters: array:1 [▼
      "file" => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile {#33 ▼
        -test: false
        -originalName: "Screen Shot 2021-03-08 at 9.33.19 AM.png"
        -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
        -error: 6
        path: ""
        filename: ""
        basename: ""
        pathname: ""
        extension: ""
        realPath: "/var/www/[my domain]/public"
        aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
        inode: false
        size: false
        perms: 00
        owner: false
        group: false
        type: false
        writable: false
        readable: false
        executable: false
        file: false
        dir: false
        link: false
      }
    ]
  }
  +cookies: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#47 ▶}
  +headers: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag {#50 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/media"
  #requestUri: "/media"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "POST"
  #format: null
  #session: Illuminate\Session\Store {#296 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -preferredFormat: null
  -isHostValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  -isSafeContentPreferred: null
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

Comment: Hi, are you sure that your error is fired by validator? because it seems more related to file upload process. How are your managing server side uploaded file? I mean are you moving the file from temp upload folder to storage folder or something like that?

Comment: Can you show ur dd request and store function?

Comment: Have you set proper read/write permission to the folder in which you're uploading the file?

Comment: Im not actually doing anything with the file, just trying to validate it and dd('valid') if it succeeds. If I get rid of the rules for the 'file' input I get the result I want, so I don't think the issue is with file handling?

Comment: @sd077 there's no store function yet, right now I'm just trying to validate the file.
Do you mean, if I dd the request before running validation?

Comment: yes run dd before validation?

Comment: Ok I'm going to post that in the OP

Comment: Its a huge object tho, are there any specific properties I should expand?

Comment: Just because you aren't doing anything with the file, doesn't mean that Laravel isn't. The fact that your uploaded file shows up as basically an empty object means that there was a problem saving the uploaded file into a temporary directory. Permissions are the most likely problem.

Comment: Ah yall were right! I was missing a temporary upload folder. I created a "tmp" dir in the root of my app and in php.ini I put: `upload_tmp_dir = "/var/www/[name of my app root]/tmp"`
...Which still didn't work! But then I found [this issue](http://tristan.terpelle.be/php-fpm-ignores-upload_tmp_dir-setting.html) so in my fpm pool config I set the following variables to that same tmp directory: php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir], env[TMP], env[TMPDIR], env[TEMP] and it worked! Don't actually need the value in php.ini either. Wish I could upvote comments!

Comment: the env variable weren't necessary actually, just php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error value of 6 means [`UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). Ensure that your system has a properly configured upload temp directory by running `php -i` from command line (or `phpinfo();` from a web page) and checking for the [`upload_tmp_dir` key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir). On a typical Linux system this will be something like `/tmp`. You can set the value in `php.ini` if needed. Ensure permissions are correct on the listed folder, such that the web server process is allowed to write to it.

Do not attempt to use one of your publicly-accessible folders as an upload directory (e.g. saving directly to `storage/app/public` or similar.) Your application code should move the file into storage [as described in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#storing-uploaded-files); something like this:

```php
public function uploadMedia(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'file' => ['required', 'file', 'image'],
        'alt' => ['required', 'string'],
    ]);
    $path = $request->file->store('images');
    return redirect()->route('whatever')->with('success', "File saved to $path");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, setting a temp upload directory worked! I'm using php-fpm pools with a different open_basedir for each app tho so I actually had to set the tmp directory value in my pool config using the variables I found [here](http://tristan.terpelle.be/php-fpm-ignores-upload_tmp_dir-setting.html) and it worked!

However since I have the open_basedir set to my app root, the app cannot access outside of its directory, so for it to work, the temp directory has to be in my app root. I am not sure how to have my temp directory not be in my app root without getting rid of this rule?

Comment: Sorry if thats not super clear, here is my phpfpm pool config that made it work, but I am unsure on how to have my temp directory be outside of the basedir...
`php_admin_value[open_basedir] = "/var/www/(app root)"
php_admin_value[upload_tmp_dir] = "/var/www/(app root)/tmp"`

Comment: It’s fine being in your app root, I was meaning public folders. I’ll clarify the answer.

Comment: I was mostly concerned about seeing `realPath: "/var/www/[my domain]/public"` in the output from `dd()`.

Comment: Ah ok, got it! Thank you for your help.